# Git submodule with same name

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-pull

I am trying to make repo like:

```
server
\ module_1
  \ library
\ module_2
  \ library
```

Whereis modules its stand-alone programs, using the same library. They should work/compile without server project. They root repos by themselfs:
for example module_2 is apache2

I cant fetch/pull source code of library.
when I try *git pull --recurse-submodules* or *git submodule forech gut pull*, etc. Its answers `everyting is up to date`, but library folder is empty.

Submodules added as:

```
git submodule add http://github.com/user/project
```

Comment: Have you run `git submodule init` to initialize the submodules? You must do this before fetch/pull.